# Connection from windows to ubuntu using RDP is slow / laggy

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I am using a remote desktop for work and it has Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed (windows at home, Ubuntu for work). I have access to this using ssh which works just fine, but for my work I need GUI. For this reason I followed the steps on this site: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/. By doing so, I was able to connect to the remote desktop using RDP and I have GUI at my disposal. The problem is that it is very "laggy", e.g. when I click and drag on the desktop it takes a full second or more for the selection box to appear, or scrolling on the internet browser is very unresponsive. The interaction is slow in general. I tried searching other sources for possible soutions, such as configuring the "experience" tab in Remote Desktop Connection to "Modem (56 kbps)" and disabling persistent bitmap caching. I have also tried disabling compositor in Ubuntu -> Window Manager Tweaks, but it did not help. Could someone help please?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sad to say, but no I have not, I just came to terms with it.